# Trigger change event when option is selected from select element

Tags: javascript, jquery

My function uses jQuery to select an option from a select element:

```
$('#id>option:eq(13)').prop("selected",true);
```

However, this does not trigger the event that is supposed to happen when the user manually selects an option. Is there a way to trigger this event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes there is a way. you can trigger events from jquery object.

```
 $('#id>option:eq(13)').prop("selected",true).trigger('change');
```

Comment: Or you can use the `change()` method without an argument: `$('#id>option:eq(13)').prop("selected",true).change();`